# Outlook for Office365 Display Message to User Before Sending

Tags: c#, winforms, outlook

I was previously using the following code and reference to create emails to users and have an outlook message window pop up prior to sending to allow the user to make changes to the email before sending...

Reference

```
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook; //v15.0.0.0
```

Snippet

```
public static void SendEmail(string To, string CC, string Subject, string Body)
{
    Outlook.Application app = new Outlook.Application();
    Outlook.MailItem mail = (Outlook.MailItem)app.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
    
    mail.Subject = Subject;
    mail.To = To;
    mail.CC = CC;
    mail.Body = Body;
    mail.Subject = Subject;
    
    if (DisplayToUser) { mail.Display(true); } //<< Important
    else { mail.Send(); }
}
```

Recently after some company updates (upgrading outlook), this code is no longer working.  I get the following error:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type
> 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass' to interface type
> 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._Application'. This operation failed
> because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface
> with IID '{00063001-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the
> following error: Element not found. (Exception from HRESULT:
> 0x8002802B (TYPE_E_ELEMENTNOTFOUND)).    at
> System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.GetCOMIPFromRCW(Object objSrc, IntPtr
> pCPCMD, IntPtr& ppTarget, Boolean& pfNeedsRelease)    at
> Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass.CreateItem(OlItemType
> ItemType)    at MyCompany.MyApp.Classes.Email.SendEmail(String
> To, String CC, String Subject, String Body, Boolean DisplayToUser,
> Boolean CcUser) in
> C:_data\MyCompany.MyApp\SourceCode-Dev\MyCompany.MyApp\Classes\Email.cs:line
> 17    at
> MyCompany.MyApp.Forms.FrmAbout.btnCommunicate_Click(Object
> sender, EventArgs e) ......

I've googled around and found plenty of examples of how to send an SMTP email through outlook but, none that seem to let me hook into the Outlook application itself to present an email to the user as I have previously done.

I've also dug around in the Microsoft.Office365.OutlookServices NuGet package without finding similar functionality.

I'm not having a problem sending emails from code, the problem is not being able to present an outlook message window to the user, using their installed outlook application.

Any idea if this functionality still exists and if so, which library to find it in or, how to get it back?

Thanks

Comment: In my experience using MS Office `Interop`, IF the office suite is updated, then the code that uses `Interop` also must be recompiled with a reference to the “updated” library. If the code is not re-compiled, then it will try and use the previous (non-updated) library which obviously may cause some problems. In your current code… have you dumped/removed the current “Interop” reference and then re-add the “Interop” reference to the new library, then re-compiled the code?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you just need to correct the declaration piece in the code:

```
public static void SendEmail(string To, string CC, string Subject, string Body)
{
    Outlook._Application app = new Outlook._Application();
    Outlook.MailItem mail = (Outlook.MailItem)app.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
    
    mail.Subject = Subject;
    mail.To = To;
    mail.CC = CC;
    mail.Body = Body;
    mail.Subject = Subject;
    
    if (DisplayToUser) { mail.Display(true); } //<< Important
    else { mail.Send(); }
}
```

If the problem persists try to repair your Office/Outlook installation. It seems the required windows registry records were corrupted.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but, switching to the interface "_Application" didn't make a difference (same error) and, I had other users in the company test and it's not working for them now either (where it previously did) so, I don't think it's a repair office installation issue.

Comment: I am sure that is it! See [Unable to cast COM object of type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass' {00063001-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} HRESULT: 0x80040155](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47332331/unable-to-cast-com-object-of-type-microsoft-office-interop-outlook-applicationc) for more information.