# I can't trigger Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.dll via .NET

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, office-interop, com-automation

I have installed Visual Studio Tools for Office (VSTO) so can use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.dll for my .Net applications. However, I get the error below. I think it is related to registry keys but I am not sure. Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.dll exists but the registry is looking for it somewhere else maybe?  I used to use this .dll library on my previous computer w/o problem. By then, I did not install VSTO but it was something similar. Do you have any idea how can I fix the issue?

3rd line raises the exception below on the screenshot

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
```

I found these [Unable to cast COM object of type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass' {00063001-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} HRESULT: 0x80040155](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47332331/unable-to-cast-com-object-of-type-microsoft-office-interop-outlook-applicationc)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ac50fa41-8d47-4fa9-81a3-914f262676af/0x80029c4a-typeecantloadlibrary?forum=vsto

but they didn't help

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please show the relevant snippets of your code that raise that exception,.

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/visual-studio-tools-for-office-runtime-overview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I backed up and deleted both Win64 Keys under

00062FFF-…
2DF8D04C…

Then it worked.

Here is my guess:

We upgraded the latest 2021 Office (64 bit) and downgraded back to 2016 Office (32 bit) and I believe this was the root of the problem.

I think VS was trying to use 64-bit Outlook but of course it was not there. So, it was showing broken references (yellow triangle sign) on references of

Microsoft.Office.Core
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook

I tried to browse and connect the library (i.e., right-click References > Add Reference > Browse) directly but had no luck. I think VS was still referring to 64-bit Office/Outlook

When I removed the Win64 keys VS was forced to use 32-bit Office which exists and it worked fine.

It took a while to figure this out I hope this answer helps other users. By the way, I don't know if deleting these registries will cause any problem when we upgrade later Office version again.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use VSTO if you automate Outlook from your .Net based application. VSTO stands for Visual Studio Tools for Office which is designed for developing Office COM add-ins.

It seems you have got some problems with Windows registry keys messed up. I'd suggest repairing MS Office to recover missed keys or try looking in the windows registry keys manually like described in the articles mentioned in your post. There is no universal fix for that.

Comment: When I remove VSTO and add the reference MS Outlook 16.0 Object Lib. The lib has a yellow warning sign and I am not able to compile my code at all. Library path is empty also while I have this as the ID {00062FFF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\9.6\0\primary. I dont know how to fix this registry. I already try reapiring MS Office but no luck. Do you have any idea where Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.dll located?

Comment: Do you have MS Outlook installed on the system?

Comment: Yes, I do. However, I realized C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16\MSOUTL.OLB (64 bit) does not exist as it shown in the registry key.  I have C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16\MSOUTL.OLB (32 bit). Do you think that would be a problem? Also, I dont understand why path is empty for Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library. Registry keys on the exception and on the reference are different too. I created the same Key values where the error says but they are pointing into same direction. I am so confused with this.

Comment: Have you tried repairing MS Office?

Comment: Yes, I did but it did not help. If I choose the platform X86 references work fine but then I can't run my application which is 64 bit ArcGIS PRO SDK. I think the problem would be solved if I have 64 bit Outlook but I don't have any control over the Office programs. If I choose Any CPU VS wants me to run as Windows Application but this is not a Windows Application. So, I got stuck pretty much I dont know if there is a solution for this. I reported to Microsoft.

Comment: You can't load x64 components into an x86 process. I'd recommend installing Office x64 in that case.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a work computer and IT will not install 64bit Office for me. I developed a similar application on my previous computer and it still works fine. I appreciate your help. For now, I will take out Outlook part from my code and I will deal with it later. Maybe, MS will find a solution.