# Read and Display Outlook Folder Names

Tags: .net, vb.net, outlook, office-interop, office-automation

I am new to VB.net and appreciate any/all help.  Years ago I developed a VB6 Learning Edition app to read all the entries in all Outlook folders.
To get started, I need help establishing a VB.net connection to Outlook, and sample code to access folders.  Once I get that basic structure, I think I can accomplish my objective.
My ultimate objective is to add a creation date to  all non-email items.

Thanks in advance.

Marvin

I tried some sample code, but had reference issues trying to get to the outlook namespace.
The sample posts provided do net seem to address VB.net

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model is common for all kind of applications. You just need to add a COM reference to your VB.NET application to be able to declare Outlook types and create a new `Application` instance. To create a new Outlook `Application` by using Automation from Visual Basic .NET, follow these steps:

Add a reference to the `Microsoft Outlook Object Library`. To do this, follow these steps:

- On the `Project` menu, click `Add Reference`.
- On the `COM` tab, locate the `Microsoft Outlook Object Library` and click `Select`.

Click `OK` in the `Add References` dialog box to accept your selections. If you receive a prompt to generate wrappers for the libraries that you selected, click `Yes`.

Vioal! Now you can use the Outlook object model in the code.

Comment: I followed your suggestions and get the following error on this statement: Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")      System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast COM object of type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._Application'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{00063001-0000-0000

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47332331/unable-to-cast-com-object-of-type-microsoft-office-interop-outlook-applicationc